# Loop updating classes instead of id fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a function that can be applied to multiple instances of a class within a page to refresh data via an AJAX call. The function works fine with only one instance on a page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getData(t, id, table, hid) {
       var autoLoad = setInterval(function (){
            $(t).load('ajax.php?id='+id+'&table='+table).html(hid);
       } , 5000);
    }

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("refresh");
    for (var i = 0, item; item = elements[i]; i++){
        var tableId = $(item).attr('id');
        var Rid = $(item).data('id');
        var Rtable = $(item).data('table');
        getData('.refresh', Rid, Rtable, tableId);
        console.log(Rid + Rtable + tableId);
    }    
});
```

The Rtable and Rid serve to determine the data pulled by AJAX w/ a PHP script. In one iteration, I'm calling this script on a table:

```
<tbody id="files" class="refresh" data-id="10" data-table="files-refresh">                                      
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the second iteration, I'm calling this script on a div:

```
<div class="refresh" data-id="10" data-table="timeload" id="content"></div>
```

The result of this is that files-refresh loads into both .refresh classes, then is overwritten by timeload. How do I modify this so that files-refresh goes to the #files table and timeload goes to #content?

Comment: Erm... change the two instances of `.refresh` to `#files` and `#content`?

Comment: Refresh is being used globally through the whole site. It's not just these two being affected. So ideally, I'd like to have the script figure out the ID based on all the .refresh classes on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getData('.refresh', Rid, Rtable, tableId);
```

should be

```
getData(tableId, Rid, Rtable);
```

with getData being

```
function getData(t, id, table) {
   var autoLoad = setInterval(function (){
        $('#' + t).load('ajax.php?id='+id+'&table='+table);
   } , 5000);
}
```